# nested xsl:for-each does not work

Tags: xslt

I woud like to make some nested loops over my xml doc

Here is my xml

```
<evolutionlist>
  <date id="22_05_2014">
    <objet>
        <identifier>1VD5-3452-8R5</identifier>
        <link>Link1</link>
        <title>EXCHANGE OF ELEMENTS</title>
    </objet>
    <objet>
        <identifier>1V24-34A2-8C5</identifier>
        <link>Link1</link>
        <title>NEW ELEMENT</title>
    </objet>
 </date>
 <date id="21_05_2014">
      <identifier>1VV4-34A2-8C5</identifier>
      <link>Link2</link>
      <title>REPLACE</title>
 </date>
</evolutionlist>
```

Ideally, I woudl like to display something like

```
 22_05_2014
   objet1 (with add infos)
   objet2  (with add infos)
 21_05_2014
   objet3   (with add infos)
```

I made:

```
<xsl:for-each  select="//date">
  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="objet">
     <tr>
     <td>  
     <xsl:value-of select="identifier"/>
     </td>
      <td>  
     <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
      </td>
      <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but I got

```
   22_05_2014  21_05_2014
   objet1
   objet2
   objet3
```

where did I go wrong ?

EDIT

I tried

```
  <xsl:for-each select="./objet">
```

for the second loop but that did not work either

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing a complete stylesheet. For all I know the logic inside the inner for-each may be producing no output, and the objetN outputs are being printed by something else later in the chain. Please edit the question to give a full stylesheet and an appropriate input sample so we can reproduce your output ourselves.

Comment: `<xsl:sort>` elements have to be the _first_ thing inside a `for-each`. If you want to output the value of these elements you need to use value-of or apply-templates.

Comment: Sorry, I meant value-of, I made an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me !
I forgot to do this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

You were right, Ian Roberts, by encouraging me do write the real code